# AGOL Web AppBuilder - Group Filter Widget with multiple layers

Tags: arcgis-online, filter, widget, operations-dashboard

I am creating a Dashboard web application for displaying utility projects using the AGOL Web AppBuilder interface. I would like to set up a Group Filter widget to filter based on a common attribute value amongst many layers. Is this possible, and if so, how can I accomplish this?

Background:
I have a number of layers in the associated webmap corresponding to their respective feature and utility type.

For example:

- Sewer Facilities Project (Point),
- Sewer Main Projects (Line)
- Water Facilities Project
- Water Main Projects
- etc.

All of these layers are joined to the same table in my hosted service .mxd. This table is set with a domain value, so all layers are sharing the same field, and the same values for this field:

- "Project in design"
- "Project in Construction"
- "Project Completed"

I would like to have a filter that displays a dropdown to select and only display projects of the selected phase -- when "Project in Design" is selected, only features with this phase will be displayed.

I currently have a filter with a drop-down selections will all layers added to it. I can select any of the phases, but once any filter is applied, all layers disappear.

[image: Settings]

[image: Widget]

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> *I would like to set up a Group Filter widget to filter based on a common attribute value amongst many layers. Is this possible, and if
>   so, how can I accomplish this?*

Yes, this is possible, and you are on the right track. In the configuration window you need to change Present Operator to **Equals** and Present Value to the specific domain value which you want to be applied to all layers. You can either type in the value or click on magnifier glass to select the value from the field in layer (Since all layers share same domain value so it will work for all)

Using the same approach you will set for other values of your domain ("Project in design", "Project in Construction", "Project Completed")